# 2nd Order Nonhomogeneous with varying coefficients

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a way to solve or get an analytical approximation to this equation?

$z''(t) + z'(t)\frac{(\omega_0 + \Delta\omega (1 - e^{-\frac{t}{\tau }}))}{Q} + z(t)(\omega_0 + \Delta\omega (1 - e^{-\frac{t}{\tau }}))^2= f_d e^{i\omega_0t} + f_e(1 - e^{-\frac{t}{\tau }})$

This is a damped driven harmonic oscillator with an exponential perturbation in force and its resonance frequency.

I've tried every method I know and couldn't get anything out of it.

Comment: is $f_e$ a function or constant? further more everything but $z,t$ are constants?

Comment: Everything that doesn't have time is constant.

Comment: What kind of methods have you tried? Has Wolfram Alpha pointed out any solution of homogeneous equation? Are some parameters small or just arbitrary? Do you really need solution of this equation and not properties of its solutions?

Comment: I've tried perturbation assuming $\Delta\omega$ is small, couldn't reproduce the numerical solution. I do need the solution for $\phi(t)$, where $z(t) = A(t)e^{i\phi(t)}$. Mathematica doesn't return any solution to homogeneous equation.